# How to import GIF files into Beamer presentation?

Tags: animation, png, gif, beamer, maple

I need to import animations from Maple into my LaTeX/Beamer presentation. I save a file in GIF format. But later I have problems converting that file into PNG. All I get is a static PNG file and can't proceed ((( What's the full code to do that in LaTeX?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [animate package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/animate/animate.pdf) to animate a series of PNGs. To get the series of PNGs from an animated GIF, use a tool like ImageMagick's convert.

Comment: Is it possible to insert GIF directly? instead of converting to series of PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help: [LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/is-there-any-way-to-include-an-animated-gif-directly)? (This is the same answer as marcog... just wanted to provide a reference to it being asked previously -- the solution was the same: the animate package).

Also, your OS will matter. I don't know that Linux (not saying you're using it) has any ability to play animated PDFs. I've tried embedding movies using LaTeX and while it "works," you can't actually view them in anything Linux offers yet. Okular is working on it, but last I checked (couple months?) it's not possible yet.

Anyway, just wanted to add that just in case you were doing everything completely right and by chance are not seeing the fruits of your labor since you're using a Linux viewer. Check your work with Acrobat on Windows to be sure.